# Filling the dropdown from sql bug

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Good afternoon people have been trying to fill a dropdown using a sql command, until so good, when I click on the dropdown it shows all the items, but when I try to click on an item in the dropdown it always returns the first item in the dropdown .... follows the codes, what i want to do is get the selected value and item from the dropdown and save it on a label for future use.

I appreciate all the support possible,

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    utilizador.Text = Me.Context.User.Identity.Name
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        escolhePerfil()
    End If

    'DropDownPerfil.DataBind()
    lbperfil2.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedItem.Text
    lbnome.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedValue
End Sub


Function escolhePerfil() As Boolean
    Dim connstring As String = "Data Source=10.2.24.17;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Pr0dUn1C0$qL;database=ePrimavera"
    Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connstring)

    Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT  u.WindowsUser,u.Email ,g.Description, u.Login FROM [ePrimavera].[dbo].[PLT_Users] as  u,[ePrimavera].[dbo].[PLT_UserGroups] as ug, [ePrimavera].[dbo].[PLT_Groups] as g where u.ID = ug.UserID And ug.GroupID = g.ID and u.WindowsUser like 'bancounico\" & utilizador.Text & "'", SQLData)
    SQLData.Open()

    Dim dtrReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()

    If dtrReader.HasRows Then
        DropDownPerfil.DataValueField = "Login"
        DropDownPerfil.DataTextField = "Description"
        DropDownPerfil.DataSource = dtrReader
        DropDownPerfil.DataBind()
    End If
    SQLData.Close()

    Return True
End Function
```

.aspx

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownPerfil" runat="server" 
      Height="16px" Width="202px" CssClass="DropBorderColor">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: add an event DropDownPerfil_SelectedIndexChanged and put the follwing lines inside the event not in page load. lbperfil2.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedItem.Text
    lbnome.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedValue

Comment: I already did that without sucess...it keeps returning the first value of the dropdown list....

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
Protected Sub DropDownPerfil_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        lbperfil2.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedItem.Text
        lbnome.Text = DropDownPerfil.SelectedValue
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get the value "too early". The value is not valid in the Page_Load, since the control's OnLoad event fired after the Page's OnLoad (Page_Load) event.

The way, what the others wrote the correct, since the Event handlig section (inclueding control's onchanged event) will process after the Load section.

For more details check the offical [ASP.NET life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) site in the MSDN

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that some (if not all) the values you are assigning to the DropDownList for `Login` are occur more than once.

When you then select an item in the DDL, if the value of that item occurs more than once, the selected index will highlight the first instance. To test this, comment out `DropDownPerfil.DataValueField = "Login"`

I am sure upon selection, it will highlight the correct item you intended on selecting.